# Without majorization how to prove this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, karamata-inequality

I'm interested by the following problem :

> Let $x_i>0$  be $n$ real numbers and $y_i>0$ be $n$ real numbers such that :
>
> $1)$ $\forall i$  and $\forall j$  indices and $i\neq j$ we have :
>   $$|x_i-x_j|\leq |y_i-y_j|$$
>
> $2)$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$$
>
> Then we have :
>   $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\geq \prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i$$

I can prove this using majorization tools it's easy but without this how to do ?

I think we can use contradiction to prove the case $n=3$ but I'm not able to find this proof.

So if you have ideas...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I will show you main steps. I suggest you try to think why these work.

(1) Enough to show when $\sum x_i=\sum y_i$ and $x_1,...,x_n$ are distinct. (Try to use limit to treat the case that some of them are equal)

(2) The set of $(y_1,...y_n)\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$ satisfying prop (1) is compact, so you would have a pair $(z_1,...z_n)$ that gives the maximum you can get.

(3) Assume that $|x_i-x_j|<|z_i-z_j|$ for some $i,j$ that $z_i,z_j$ are adjacent among $z_1,...,z_n$ and $z_i<z_j$(remember that $z_1,...z_n$ are distinct by prop(1)). Check that a new pair $(z_1',...z_n')$ that $z_r'=z_r$ for $r\neq i,j$ and $z_i'=z_i+d$, $z_j'=z_j-d$ with $z_j'-z_i'=|x_i-x_j|$ also satisfies prop (1), so such $(z_1,...z_n)$ does not give the maximum.

(4) Now you observe that the maximum is obtained only when $\{x_1,...x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ are the same set, and so we are done.

Comment: In summary, try to think the maximizer of RHS and try to narrow down the gap between two adjacent points by dragging them toward their midpoint so that RHS gets bigger. You cannot do that only when all inequalities in (1) are actually equal.